# locally bounded function definition (compact neighborhoods?)

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, functions

I have a function $f:\mathbb{R}^d \times [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}^d$ where $d\in \mathbb{N}^*$ and $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $a<b$. The definition of $f$ is locally bounded is the following:

for any $(x,t)\in \mathbb{R}^d \times [a,b]$ there exists a neighborhood $K$ of $(x,t)$ such that $f(K)$ is a bounded set.

My question is: does the set $K$ has to be compact ?

Comment: no, it need not